# Wordpress 4.1 update broke theme

Tags: installation, upgrade

How do I roll back WP install? Sometime in the last 20 minutes, my website updated to 4.1, which swapped to the 2015 theme and refuses to let me use my template because:

```
The following themes are installed but incomplete. Themes must have a stylesheet and a template.

Name    Description 
blankslate/css  Template is missing.
```

This is so very very not cool. Please help!

Comment: Upload your theme again.

Comment: Randy, there's no such thing as WP2015. The most recent default them is called Twenty Fifteen, but this is entirely separate from the version of your core installation. The error you're seeing indicates that one or more of the required theme files for the "blankslate" theme are missing. As @Roberthue commented above, you should re-upload your template to replace these files and then re-active your theme.

Comment: The package could not be installed. The theme is missing the style.css stylesheet.

Comment: restore from backup..

Comment: Added css file with proper header text, reuploaded. Why this version of WP wouldn't account for sub-directory css is beyond me. Rude awakening for a Monday.

Comment: @Roberthue since you were first would you like to pose that as an answer?

Comment: @RandyHall just did. I am glad you got everything working again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of these errors are caused by damaged or corrupt theme files.

> Upload theme files/directory again and you will be fine.

Strange things happen sometimes, that's why it's always recommended to keep a backup of your WordPress files and database before updating.

Comment: Also note that this was an automatic update and this particular theme was broken by having the CSS files in a sub-folder instead of just sitting in the root theme directory.